# MFC DateTime picker format changes when I open visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, visual-studio-2003

I have a form in which I have placed a MFC DateTimePicker control. I set its format property to `Time`. Work with my app and everything is fine. But when I close visual studio and open it the next time, format has changed to its default value.
I noticed everything saves just fine, since if I build my solution using devenv.exe at command line the dialogs are displayed correctly. So it seems to me that whenever I open VS, it changes my setting.
How do I avoid this?

**EDIT:**

- Tried VS2010, the problem did not occur there. However the project I'm working on is using VS2003 so the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

congrats,

you are the 210th user of visual studio who found that bug but don't worry this will not show you from visual studio 2005 onward.

As per release note by Microsoft this issue came due to the,

**behavior occurs because a problem exists in the Visual Studio .NET resource editor for Visual C++ projects.**

For more information on this please seen following bug of visual studio resource editor.

[FIX: The Format property of the DateTimePicker control reverts to Short Date in Visual Studio .NET 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838388)